# it is giving error in declaring variable gender (flutter)

Tags: flutter, variables, syntax-error, declaration, flutter-widget

[error in adding variable name gender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9igWa.png)

```
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
```

Gender selectedGender;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Comment: Please share a full reproducable code.

Comment: Please show your code instead of showing up a photo https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code and syntax, it seems like Gender is an [enum](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types). Hard to confirm without complete code but you can try creating a Gender enum like this.

```
enum Gender { female, male, /* other genders */ }
```

Then you can start using the enum like below:

```
Gender userGender = Gender.male;
```

or in your code:

```
Gender selectedGender = Gender.male;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do is:

```
enum Gender{
  male,
  female,
  noGender,
}
```

Then:

```
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
   Gender selectedGender =Gender.noGender;
}
```

Or

```
enum Gender{
  male,
  female,
}
```

Then use sound_null_safety operator.

```
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
Gender? selectedGender;
}
```